# Fastest throughput Local, RAM Cahced DB

Tags: database, redis, memcached, berkeley-db, embedded-database

I'm looking for a DB solution for a high performance application.
The database will need to be local and stored in RAM for performance and will be several GB in size.
It will be local to the application, but it may be accessed by multiple processes running on the machine (up to 40). The data in the DB is immutable once it's been inserted and I only need a basic key value store rather than anything relational.
The obvious candidates are Memcached and Redis, but I believe they both have limitations with overhead and bottlenecks from the network component.
Something like Berkeley DB would also appear to be ideal, but it's only single process as far as I can see.
Throughput is the most important consideration (more so than latency).

Comment: You might check out LMDB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Memory-Mapped_Database, as its use of shared memory sounds like just what you need.

Comment: Interestingly I'm currently writing some LMDB test code!